# Laravel - White page after uploading from local

Tags: php, laravel

I uploaded my Laravel project from my local WAMP server to my web server.

Now I'm getting a white site.

I already changed the the URL in /app/config/app.php but still getting a white site.
All files belong the FTP user ( 508/508 ).

I've a server based on cPanel / Apache / PHP 5.4 / Centos.

Comment: Have you fixed the .htaccess?

Comment: Yep i already tried the .htaccess from http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add write permissions to your `app/storage` folder - laravel needs to store session, view etc. data in this path.

Comment: I added write permissions to **app/storage/*** to the folders. Now it`s working, thanks :)